# Regular expression match specific key words

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use regexp to match some specific key words.

For those codes as below, I'd like to only match those IFs at first and second line, which have no prefix and postfix. The regexp I am using now is `\b(IF|ELSE)\b`, and it will give me all the IFs back.

```
IF A > B THEN STOP
   IF B < C THEN STOP
LOL.IF
IF.LOL
IF.ELSE
```

Thanks for any help in advance.
And I am using http://regexr.com/ for test.
Need to work with JS.

Comment: Does the `IF` always appear at the beginning of a line? For example, would you want to match the IF in `TEST IF SOMETHING`?

Comment: `\b(IF|ELSE)\b ` add a space to the end?

Comment: @nickb no, the position is randomly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you're looking for, assuming you've added the `m` flag for multiline:

```
(?:^|\s)(IF|ELSE)(?:$|\s)
```

It's comprised of three groups:

1. `(?:^|\s)` - Matches either the beginning of the line, or a single space character
2. `(IF|ELSE)` - Matches one of your keywords
3. `(?:$|\s)` - Matches either the end of the line, or a single space character.

[Regexr](http://regexr.com/3car5)

Comment: Thanks! I have tested it. It works. For 2nd line, it will math those white spaces at beginning.

Comment: this works, but I think its better practice to use lookaround as described in my answer as its more explcit

Comment: @Andreas Linden I have tested ur answer, but it did not work.

Comment: nickb I just realized that at 4th line, it will match all the white space after the string, and thats not I want. :(

Comment: @JayHaojieCui - What language are you using the regex in? JS? Which line are you referring to?

Comment: still something is weird with JS regex or with Regexer as it matches spaces around the IF though the expression does not tell it to xD

Comment: Thanks again. This is weird. :0

Comment: @JayHaojieCui - So the problem you're facing using Javascript is that you have to consume something to get to your keywords. When you had `\b(IF|ELSE)\b` you were consuming a word boundary `\b` to get to the keyword, but you quickly found that it failed because the position between a period and a character is a word boundary. I'm not sure which line you are referring to when you say "4th line", so if you could be more specific with which test case is not correct, I could try to update my answer.

Comment: @nickb I have tested you answer again. I believe that was something with RegExr before.  it works fine now, but it will match some white space around IF. Could it just match exact IF? Appreciate your help.

Comment: @JayHaojieCui - Yes, it's currently intended to match the whitespace around it. However, the capturing group within the regex doesn't include the whitespace. So, if you grab `$1`, it should be the keyword without whitespace. [This regexr](http://regexr.com/3carn) shows you what `$1` contains.

Comment: @nickb oh ok. Thanks, appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with lookaround (lookahead + lookbehind). this is what you really want as it explicitly matches what you are searching. you don't want to check for other characters like string start or whitespaces around the match but exactly match "IF or ELSE not surrounded by dots"

```
/(?<!\.)(IF|ELSE)(?!\.)/g
```

explanation:

- use the g-flag to find all occurrences
- `(?<!X)Y` is a negative lookbehind which matches a Y not preceeded by an X
- `Y(?!X)` is a negative lookahead which matches a Y not followed by an X

working example: https://regex101.com/r/oS2dZ6/1

PS: if you don't have to write regex for JS better use a tool which supports the posix standard like regex101.com

Comment: Have you tested this? A negative lookbehind begins with `(?<!`, not `(<!?`. Also, the OP is testing on regexr which uses JS's regex engine, which doesn't support negative lookbehinds (at least according to regexr).

Comment: oops that was a typo. thank you. updated post with link. this is posix standard, there was no limitation to make it work with js

Comment: agree with nickb. /(?<!\.)(IF|ELSE)(?!\.)/g works, but it did not work with JS.

Comment: @ Andreas Linden Your answer is quite helpful and it works correctly. But I need to work with JS. Thanks again.